# POS=... when using pgi compilers

Tags: fortran, pgi

I'm trying to update/re-write a bunch of code that should be able to be compiled by all of the major fortran compilers.  I have access to `ifort`, and `gfortran` and a relatively old (?) version of the pgi compiler (version 7.2.5).  The code compiles fine with gfortran and ifort, but portland group's compiler complains at a line that looks like:

```
open(unit=82,file=fname,status=status,form='UNFORMATTED',access='STREAM')
write(82,POS=file_pos) iheader    !<= mpif90 complains here
```

I'm actually using `mpif90` which is a wrapper around `pgf90`, but that shouldn't make a difference.  (`iheader` is simply an integer array with 20 elements).  Do more modern versions the portland group compiler support this?

Comment: Are you sure this version supports stream access properly? This is a Fortran 2003 feature.

Comment: @VladimirF -- I recognize that.  The compiler complains about the syntax at the `POS=...` line, but I suppose this question could be more general than that. Does portland group even support the stream IO introduced in the f2003 standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a look at the [PGI fortran reference](http://www.pgroup.com/doc/pgifortref.pdf), It looks like they still don't support stream IO (It's not listed in the allowable access strings, page 69).  I guess I'll need to re-write that code ... If they don't support stream IO, then they probably don't support `POS=...` either.